# React Async/Await Get data with request body

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, axios

Im trying to get data that requires request body and am having trouble. With other post requests, {requestedThings} worked fine but with get request, it gives me an error

Can someone help me how to fix this ?

```
async function initSurvey(userNo: number) {
  return await loginApi.get(`/user/survey`, { userNo: userNo });
}
```

[image]

I am getting below message  :

TS2345: Argument of type '{ userNo: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AxiosRequestConfig'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'userNo' does not exist in type 'AxiosRequestConfig'.
46 | async function initSurvey(userNo: number) {

> 47 |   return await loginApi.get(`/user/survey`, { userNo: userNo });
> |                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> 48 | }
> 49 |
> 50 | export {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get` request method does not have request body according to [MDN specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET). If you are using `axios` you should do as described below or send request without body according to your `loginApi` API.

```
await axios.get('/user/survey', {
    params: {
      userNo
    }
)
```